# RangeError 2066, XML and AS3

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I'm working with XML and Flash. I tried to pass XML values to my timer and got a Range Error. How do I fix this?

**My Error**
RangeError: Error #2066: The Timer delay specified is out of range.
    at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.utils::Timer()
    at svrReadyXML_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

**My SWF** 'Receives XML for Timer function'

```
import flash.display.Sprite; 
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.utils.Timer; 
import flash.events.TimerEvent; 

var timer:Timer; 
timer = new Timer( speed );
var speed:Number = Number( myXML.TIMER.text() );
var fcount:int = 0;
var count:int = 0;

timer = new Timer(speed); 
//timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);     
timer.start();

//LOAD XML
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("time.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

//PARSE XML
function processXML(e:Event):void {
myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
trace(myXML.COUNT.text()); 
trace(myXML.FCOUNT.text()); 
trace(myXML.TIMER.text()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to read `myXML.TIMER` value before loading your XML file. It probably returns null, which causes your problem.
Try to initialize your timer in your `processXML` function.

```
function processXML(e:Event):void {
myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
timer = new Timer( Number(myXML.TIMER.text()) );
timer.start();
}
```